# IIS: There was a problem reading metadata from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, temp

I am having this most annoying issue when I try to rebuild my solution I get 4 lines of:

There was a problem reading metadata from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyWebSiteName...

I tried restarting IIS, so I could delete the temp files, but they're locked.

How can I fix this annoyance, it only happens on a release build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try right-clicking on the Web Project and selecting **"Clean"**?

Often times if that doesn't work a restart of Visual Studio fixes this.

Comment: That is exactly the solution that fixed my problem.